# Azure and MS Excel addin in vba

Tags: azure

We have at the moment an MS Excel addin in vba. That file is on our network. The disk where the file is store is UNIX. We control the access via UNIX policy. We provide a shortcut to the user to use this addin. The addin perform read/write text file and read/write on an MS access database (also on UNIX). The addin download template (also on unix) to the user local drive. When the addin open the template it does create a project reference to the template. With this reference, the template have access to the addin functionality.

Our desire is to put and run this addin on the cloud using remotes apps to extend the use on an Ipad.

I would like to know what I need to create (on azure 100% cloud solution) after the remote apps to store the following element and have access to them on the cloud via the Ipad.

Excel addin

Excel template

Text file generate by the add in

The access database